# NPM Grant OAuth Middleware "invalid_redirect" error

Tags: node.js, express, oauth-2.0, jawbone, grant-oauth

I have been trying to use this [elegant looking package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grant) to authenticate with Jawbone API. But I keep getting this error -

[image]

I have configured my "app" with the Jawbone API service to use these Redirect URIs -

[image]

My config file looks like this -

```
module.exports = {

    'server': {
        'protocol'  : 'https',
        'host'      : 'localhost',
        'port'      : 5000,
        'callback'  : '/done',
        'transport' : 'session',
        'state'     :  true
    },

    'jawbone' : {
       'key'        : '6f*********', 
       'secret'     : '9b************************',
       'callback'   : '/connect/jawbone/callback',
       'scope'      : ['basic_read', 'sleep_read'],
    }
}
```

I've tried to follow the [authors](http://simov.github.io/) [examples](https://github.com/simov/grant) to produce an app.js like this -

```
var config      = require('./config');
var express     = require('express');
var session     = require('express-session');
var Grant       = require('grant-express');
var grant       = new Grant(require('./config.js'));
var bodyParser  = require('body-parser') 
var app         = express()
var Purest      = require('purest');
var jawbone     = new Purest({provider:'jawbone'});
var https       = require('https');
var fs          = require('fs');

var logger = require('morgan')

    app.use(logger('dev'))
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
    app.use(session({secret:'grant'}));
    app.use(grant);

    app.get('/done', function (req, res) {
      console.log(req.query);
      res.end(JSON.stringify(req.query, null, 2));
    });

    /*
jawbone.get('users/@me', {
  auth:{bearer:'[ACCESS_TOKEN]'}
}, function (err, res, body) {
  // body is a parsed JSON object containing the response data
  console.log(body);
})
*/
var sslOptions = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('./.server.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./.server.crt')
    };
var secureServer = https.createServer(sslOptions, app).listen(config.server.port, function(){
    console.log('Listening on port ' + config.server.port);
});
```

I assume I'm making a noob-error and probably misreading the documentation or examples. Can someone point out what I have misconfigured?

Comment: The `host` value should be `localhost:5000` I know it's kind of misleading.

Comment: Oh, that helps. Now I get a "This webpage has a redirect loop" error. What am I doing wrong with my routes? Can't I just res.send() the results to /done ?

Comment: The `callback` key contains the path on your server where you want to receive the results. The `/connect/jawbone/callback` route is used internally by Grant, so you can't use that route. Also the `callback` key for the `jawbone` provider overrides the global `callback` key specified for the `server`. Just set the `callback` key for `jawbone` like this `callback:'/handle_callback'` and you'll get the results inside the `/handle_callback` route (all of this is in the docs btw).

Comment: Thank you. I was receiving '{}' and assumed this was a failed auth attempt. But I guess this means success. If you want to submit this as an answer, I'll accept it. Nice work on this module BTW.  Thank you.

Comment: Posted the answer, hopefully it'll be helpful for other people as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments above your configuration should look like this:

```
{

    'server': {
        'protocol'  : 'https',
        'host'      : 'localhost:5000',
        'transport' : 'session',
        'state'     :  true
    },

    'jawbone' : {
       'key'        : '6f*********', 
       'secret'     : '9b************************',
       'callback'   : '/handle_jawbone_callback',
       'scope'      : ['basic_read', 'sleep_read'],
    }
}
```

Currently there is no separate `port` option, so in case you don't have some sort of virtual host on top of your app, you should append the port number to the `host` value - `host:'localhost:5000`.

For `callback` key you should always set the path on your server where you want to receive the results from the OAuth flow. The `/connect/jawbone/callback` route that you specify for `redirect_uri` of your OAuth application is reserved for Grant, so you can't use that route directly.

For example you can set the final route like this: `callback:'/handle_jawbone_callback'`.

All of this is documented in the module's [readme file](https://github.com/simov/grant) as well.